# angular7 parent resolver not called when child route called

Tags: angular, navigation, angular7, resolve, angular7-router

these are my routes

parent module routes:

```
{
    path: 'users',
    loadChildren: '../users/users.module#UsersModule',
    canActivate: [RoleGuardService],
    data: { expectedRole: 'System Admin', showNavBar: false }
  }
```

child module routes:

```
const routes: Routes = [{
path: '',
resolve: { users: UsersListResolverService },
 children: [
   {
    path: '',
    component: UsersListingComponent,
   }, {
   path: 'add',
   component: UserAddEditComponent,
   }
 ]
}];
```

I need "users" in both the components so i have put the resolve at parent.
now the issue is when i redirect fro add UserAddEditComponent to UsersListingComponent resolver not called.

I have add button in  UserAddEditComponent  component and i navigate like this

```
this.router.navigate(['/sites', this.siteId, 'users'], navigationExtras);
```

I get all the "users" but old users when refresh page then only list data get updated.

can someone help me to check out why this happens?

Comment: Can you verify which route is shown when placing the mouse on top of the button? Or your button execute an event?